# URL auto change cause error "file not found" when I download from url

Tags: java, android

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("http://dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi.rss");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/xa-hoi.rss");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLenght = 0;
        while((bufferLenght = is.read(buffer)) != -1){
            fos.write(buffer, 0, bufferLenght);
        }
        fos.close();
        fos.flush();
        is.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

LogCat: 03-05 05:11:35.620: W/System.err(3437): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://m.dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi.rss.

This problem is url "dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi.rss" change to "m.dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi.rss"
Please help me!. Thank you everyone.

Comment: have you taken permission for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in manifest?

Comment: Don't edit an answer to respond to it- instead, click the "add comment" link and add a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have written following inside manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thank you but this problem is url "dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi.rss" change to "m.dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi.rss"

Comment: okay... so is your real phone refers to mobile website instead of original one?

Answer (score 1):

use [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html)  instead of static string for getting SDCARD path as :

```
String sdcardpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(sdcardpath+"/xa-hoi.rss");
```

and make sure u have added sdcard permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` :-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thank you but this problem is url "dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi.rss" change to "m.dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi.rss"

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
 OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/xa-hoi.rss");
```

Replace with:

```
OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("xa-hoi.rss");
```